# How to do linear convolution for two matrix column by column in python

Tags: python, matlab, convolution

I have tow matrices, I need to do convolution between each column from matrix `A` to the correspondent column from matrix `B` and store the results in matrix `y`.

for example, `A` is a complex matrix of dimension `10 x 5`  and matrix `b` is complex matrix too of dimension `7 x 5`, so I can do that in matlab as below :

```matlab
A = randi(10,5) + 1j*randi(10,5); 
B = randi(7,5) + 1j*randi(7,5); 
for i = 1 : 5 
    y(:,i) = conv(A(:,i),B(:,i));
end
```

So when I built that step in python as below :

```py
for i in range(5):
    y[:,i]= np.convolve(A[:, i], B[:, i])
```

it gives me an error of

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

please anyone can help to solve that issue. I'm still newbie in working by python!!

Comment: You gotta initialize y first. `y=np.zeros((10,5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the above comment,  you can add this line before the for loop,

```
y = np.zeros((10+7-1,5))
```

As you know the length of resulted vector of convolution of two vectors is the sum of their length - 1, for that I used the (10+7-1) and that's generalized for any two vectors.

Good luck